# Change variable on every loop in for-next?

Tags: vb.net, variables, for-loop, textbox

### Explanation to my Problem

I am designing a program, which has to get value from multiple variables. Each variable is declared explicitly first as integer. Then, I have a for-next loop in which a variable will be assigned a value, each time for different variable for a different `textbox`.

There are 25 `textbox` and on every loop, variable should be changed as well as the `textbox`. For, example, the name of textbox should be changed from `textbox1` to `textbox2` and variable should be changed from a to b and then c and so on.

The advantage is I haven't renamed the `textbox`, and they are in proper order and would be easy to manage.

The problem that I am facing is, I can do it with two strings, `"Textbox" & numvariable & ".text"` but this will be string, not a textbox control.

### Code

```
For start = 1 to 10
      a = Textbox1.Text 'a should change to b and textbox1 should change to textbox2 on next loop
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the textboxes belong to the Controls collection of the form they are one (or more precisely of the container they are in. For example they could be located inside a panel).
You can access a control by name by using this controls collection.
As for enumaration of the variables, try to create an array:

```
Dim cont() As String = {a, b, c, d, e}
For i = 1 To 5
    CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & i.ToString), TextBox).Text = cont(i-1)
Next
```

Technically you would not need the type conversion in this specific case, since the `.Text` property is inherited by the textbox but it's more general to do it. Other properties might be specific to the object's type and you can access these only after you convert the object in the collection to the correct type.
Lastly beware that arrays start with the index 0 and not 1 (Therefore the `cont(i-1)` part).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly! Just I had to take something other than `e` as `e` is already a member of a control.